# Is it wrong to use a link in this situation

Tags: gui-design

I'm designing a language system that makes recommendations based on the text the user has entered in an accompanying text area. My question is, is my use of link styles in this situation wrong, if so, what would be a better alternative. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Note: When a user clicks on the link, the incorrect word in the text editor will be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't say it's wrong but **it could be better**

The standard use for links is to direct you to another webpage, usually with content described in the link text. That's not what you are doing so you could argue it's incorrect use of links.

With the way you've used the link it's not very clear what will happen when you click it. I would suggest removing the link and highlighting the 'correction' word in a different way, for example making it bold. Next to it I would place a button with a more descriptive text such as 'replace'.

Answer (score 0):

Googles "Did you mean" had a similar styling so I would assume users are familiar with this pattern. Google now removed the underline. I'm not sure for what reason, to improve aesthetics or usability? You could consider this as well.

Two questions to hopefully help you further. Can you show the text suggestions more in context? It is more convenient and intuitive to see the suggestions at the time of typing close to the text. And what happens when there are multiple suggestions? How are they displayed?